# Original object disappear when .append() is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append, push

I made a little quick "Add to favorites" type program for practice. You click a "favorite" box and it adds it to the sidebar.

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCBradley3k/sdKgP/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var favorites = [];
    var counter = 0;

    $('#container, #container2, #container3').click(function(){
       favorites.push($(this))            
        $('.favorite').append(favorites);
    });  
});
```

I would like it to continue to do what it does, but not let the original container disappear.

Also, instead of saying `$(container 1, 2, 3, etc)`, is there a way for it to just know which container is clicked and then move that specific one. Like what if I had 50 containers? I wouldn't want to list them all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9Dmcg/3/

Give the containers a class and bind to the class.

```
$('.containers').bind('click', function(){

    favorites.push($(this).clone())

    $('.favorite').append(favorites);
});
```

Looks like jcubic has the correct syntax for the clone

Comment: You mean wrap all the containers in a div?

Comment: Only one to answer both questions, but I would fork a new fiddle to make it easier for the OP to understand.

Comment: @JamesMitchell No, why wrap all the containers?  You want to perform the action when any container is clicked.  Create a container class and put the class on every new container.  That way it'll bind to the actual container clicked, allowing you to capture it with $(this)

Comment: @BinaryTox1n  Excellent point.  I added a working JSFiddle to make it more apparent

Comment: Now would there be a way to delete an item in the side bar (and then have the others change positions accordingly?)

Comment: @JamesMitchell It seems as if that is another question altogether :).  Naturally there has to be a way but that will make your logic much more complex.  If such, how does your function know if it's adding or removing?  My suggestion would be to play around with it and if you get stuck, come right back here and make a new question, since this question is technically resolved.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've also noticed adds it more than once when it is clicked on again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
$('#container, #container2, #container3').click(function(){
  $(this).clone().appendTo('.favorite');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clone jquery function http://jsfiddle.net/sdKgP/1/

```
$('#container, #container2, #container3').click(function(){

    favorites.push($(this).clone())

    $('.favorite').append(favorites);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sdKgP/25/

You should get ride of id for container. In your case as you might have many bookmark containers so u wouldn't like to add css for each one. so you need to change your css as well.

CSS

```
#sidenav {
height:700px;
width:250px;
border: 1px solid rgb(150,150,150);
position:absolute;
display:inline;
float: right;
left: 125px;
}

.container {
height:50px;
width:75px;
border:1px solid #000;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

DOM

```
<div style="float:left">
<div class="container">
 Favorite
 </div>

<div class="container">
  Favorite
</div>

<div class="container">
  Favorite
 </div>
</div>
 <div>
 <div id="sidenav">
  <div class="favorite"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var favorites = [];
   var counter = 0;
  $('.container').click(function(){
    favorites.push($(this).clone());
    $('.favorite').append(favorites);
 });
});
```